How to map jsonb column from Postgres into Java List<Enum> using Hibernate?
I have a view in Java Spring app:
public interface MyView {
  List<MyEnum> getMyEnums();
}

And column in Postgres table:
create table my_table
(
    id               bigserial primary key,
    myEnums          jsonb
);

In this column can be values like this: ["VAL1", "VAL2"] or [] etc.
And I have a query method:
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """
            SELECT id,
                   my_table.myEnums AS myEnums          
            FROM my_table ...""")
    List<MyView> findAll(Collection<Long> ids);

Hiberenate can get only String from jsonb (for example "["VAL1", "VAL2"]") column but not map into List (I getting an exception).
Is there are a simple way to map jsonb column into List?
